# Can I force ActiveRecord to save a model when a string field is modified in place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model that has a long string field. Actually, this string represents an array which I would like to modify in-place instead of copying the entire string.

For example lets say `Somemodel` has a string field `array`. Then the following fails to save:

```
m = Somemodel.first
m.array[someindex] = somevalue
m.save
```

Actually, `save` returns true by it seems to check that `array` has the same `object_id` and decides that the model has not changed and skips the roundtrip to the database.

I ended up using the following workaround:

```
m = Somemodel.first
a = String.new(m.array) # remember, the array is represented as a string
a[someindex] = somevalue
m.array = a
m.save
```

Note that `m.array` has to be set after modifying its value because `save` looks at value and not only `object_id`.

This feels cumbersome AND requires the entire string to be copied. Not nice for large array. **Can I tell `save` to bypass these is-model-modified checkes without foregoing validation tests?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html:

> If an attribute is modified in-place then make use of [attribute_name]_will_change! to mark > that the attribute is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, implement the hash method on your objects.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15458